# jhipster hotreload - application won't start

Tags: jhipster

I ve installed jhipster and I am trying to run my application with STS. I want to test the hotreload functionnality.

So I run Application.java class and I m getting a lot of error, the first one beginning by :

```
[ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase - A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) [na:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_60-ea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_60-ea]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Did I miss something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need STS, just Eclipse with the J2EE stuff.

I've imported the [sample jhipster](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app) in Eclipse (without STS) as a Maven project and everything was OK, after installing the maven dependencies.

To run the project, run as an application and search for the Application (com.mycompany.myapp.Application) in Eclipse.